# Can police actually commandeer a vehicle from a citizen for pursuit?

Tags: united-states, police, private-property

One sees it in films and tv all the time...

> Officer: *"He's getting away! Sir, I'm commandeering this vehicle. Please get out!"*

Is this *actually* feasible?

Is a private citizen *required* to relinquish their privately owned vehicle if a police officer requests it, merely so the officer can continue a pursuit?

US Law. Assuming the citizen is legally authorized to drive and the officer has no other official reason to stop the driver. And the citizen is doing *nothing* to otherwise impede any pursuit.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, but subject to the specifics of state law, a person may be [required to assist a police officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refusing_to_assist_a_police_officer#United_States). For instance [in Alabama](https://law.justia.com/codes/alabama/2006/13297/13a-10-5.html)

> A person commits the crime of refusing to aid a peace officer if, upon
> command by a peace officer identified to him as such, he fails or
> refuses to aid such peace officer in:
>
> (1) Effecting or securing a lawful arrest; or
>
> (2) Preventing the commission by another person of any offense.

[In Washington](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.76.030), the obligations is much narrower:

> A person is guilty of refusing to summon aid for a peace officer if,
> upon request by a person he or she knows to be a peace officer, he or
> she unreasonably refuses or fails to summon aid for such peace
> officer.

Washington seems to be in the minority, compared to Alabama.

Comment: But does relinquishing privately owned property constitute "assisting"? I mean helping to hold down a suspect when asked by an officer - or telling an officer which way a suspect ran - is quite different than giving up a vehicle worth thousands of dollars, which may be needed to earn an income, and may ultimately be damaged beyond repair due the (assumed) chase.

Comment: My thought is that seizing a vehicle in this manner would fall under "unreasonable search and seizure" as stated in the 4th amendment of the Constitution. And *that* overrules any officer request regardless of the officer's reasoning.

Comment: @Scott There is a lot of case law that what would normally be unreasonable, and a violation of the 4th amendment, might be reasonable in an emergency. If there is an imminent danger to life, a court might well hold that the officer's actions were reasonable in the circumstances.

Comment: Understood @richardb I could see it possibly if it were commandeering the vehicle to take someone to a hospital (in which case, many people wouldn't have an issue driving)... but to commandeer the vehicle in order to continue chasing a suspect. I, personally, do not see how that would *ever* qualify as an "emergency"? Frankly, I can't see how relinquishing privately owned property merely upon request is ever "assisting" any officer.